# How do I get "time ago" with a date provided by mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, datetime, date-fns

I searched around the documentions of some popular time parsing and formatting libraries like `Day.js` and `date-fns`, but I didn't really get it.

My `Node.js` backend queries the datetime of creation of a record in my `MySQL` database and sends it to the frontend (im using `React`). On the frontend I want to find the time differnce between the date from the database (which   looks like this `2020-12-04T15:39:40.000Z` and is already parsed from json to a javscript object) and the current datetime.
Social media sites for example have something like "postet 2 days ago".
I have seen solutions using no libraries just vanilla javascript, but they seem to long and I didn't really understand them. I would like to use a library which streamlines this.
What do you think would be the best approach?

Comment: Alternatively you can use the `DATEDIFF()` function in your MySQL query. It returns the number of days between two date values: `SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), 'your_saved_date') as days FROM table ...`.

Comment: You've probably noticed, in this site, if you hover your mouse over a text string like `answered 2 minutes ago` you get a tooltip popup with the timestamp. In my opinion, that's nice UI design.

Answer (score 22):

date-fns has a built in localized function to output a string like that:

https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/formatDistance

So you could use:

```
formatDistance(
    new Date('2020-12-04T15:39:40.000Z'),
    new Date(),
   { addSuffix: true }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) method of [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com) library.
Your code may be something like this:

```
diffDays = currentDate.diff(databaseDate, "days");
diffString = `posted ${diffDays} days ago`;
```

Comment: As `moment.js` is not maintained anymore, better to use  date-fns lib (https://date-fns.org/)

Comment: can you modify text like "ends in" or "ended" for future and past dates?